# How to check if each element in a list is the same (set) variable

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to make Python return True whenever it is given a list that contains only the number 6 and false if it contains anything else. So:

```
list1 = [3, 6, 1] # Would return False
list2 = [5, 5, 5] # Would return False
list3 = [6, 6, 6] # Would return True
```

I think it has something to do with any(), but as far as I know that can only be used to see if the list contains only the same element and not if it contains only a specific element.

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: Use the `all()` function.

Comment: What have you tried? There's like a million ways to do this. You could use `all`, `fold`, a for-loop, explicit recursion...

Comment: I've tried _if 6 not in list: pass_ with _else: #Do something_, but it goes to _else_ no matter what the list contains

Comment: ```all(n == 6 for n in lyst)```

Comment: Right, that did it. I misunderstood how all() and any() are used. Thanks!

Comment: What should be the output for `l = []`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-set) like this:

```
set(l) == {6}
```

**Example:**

```
>>> l = [6, 6, 6]
>>> set(l) == {6}
True
>>> 
>>> l = [6, 6, 6, 5]
>>> set(l) == {6}
False
```

Another approach is using [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) with a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions):

```
all(item == 6 for item in l)
```

Comment: That's a pretty verbose way to check `s == {6}`.

Comment: You don't need the `len(s) == 1` check either, because that's implicit in `s == {6}`. You can collapse the whole thing down to `set(l) == {6}`.